# mfrow( multiple graphics in r)

Tags: r, plot

For some reason I can't get multiple graph to get plotted using the `mfrow` function. It just replaces the graph not plotting beside it.

Here is the code:

```
mmodel=monthglm(formula=monthcount~1,data=azithro,family=poisson(),
offsetpop=NULL,offsetmonth=TRUE, refmonth=9)


mmodel2=monthglm(formula=monthcount~1,data=levo,family=poisson(),
offsetpop=NULL,offsetmonth=TRUE, refmonth=9)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mmodel)
plot(mmodel2)
```

For some reason the second graph is replacing the first one not plotting beside it.

Comment: Could you please provide a small example data set to let others reproduce your models?

Comment: You may need to shuts down the current device by `dev.off()` before running the code.

Comment: mmodel2= monthglm(formula = cvd ~ 1,data = CVD, family = poisson(),
offsetpop = pop/100000, offsetmonth = TRUE, refmonth = 7)  if you require sample data set is from the season package and just rerun this model twice change the refmonth to 9 and try to plot both models gives same problem

Comment: ya CathG nope wont work saids restore.par is not a graphic parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that are unclear to me, the last line of the `plot.monthglm` function resets the graphical parameters of the current device:

```
par(op) ## op is previously set as op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
```

So when you call `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` before the first plot, this gets called again after creating the plot. Any subsequent plot then gets drawn over the previous one.

To get around this, you can replace the offending line with something else (here, I borrowed a typical last line seen in many `plot` functions). You should check to make sure that `30` is still the correct part of the function to replace:

```
body(plot.monthglm)[[30]]
## par(op)
body(plot.monthglm)[[30]] <- substitute(invisible(NULL))
```

Then things should work as expected:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot.monthglm(mmodel, main="my first model")
plot.monthglm(mmodel, main="my second model")
```

I suggest contacting the maintainer of the `season` package (`maintainer("season")`) to ask whether this is an intended feature of the function.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH... u have no idea how may times i ve being banging my head against my desk. Thanks to all who have helped as well!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `split.screen` and define the panels however you like. This might be how the creator of `plot.monthglm` works and never noticed the `mfrow` bug.

```
split.screen(c(2,2))
for(i in 1:4){
    screen(i)
    plot(mmodel, main=paste("Model", i))
}
```

[image: split.screen and plot.monthglm]

Comment: Nice, did not know `split.screen` so far. Unfortunately, it seems not well integrated with R markdown (at least not in RStudio).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mmodel)
par(new=T)
plot(mmodel2)
```

**Example**

```
mmodel = monthglm(formula=cvd~1, data=CVD, family=poisson(), offsetpop=CVD$pop/100000, offsetmonth=TRUE, refmonth=6)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mmodel, main="my first model")
par(new=T)
plot(mmodel, main="my second model")
```

[image]

Comment: Well it does work for 2 graphs in one row but if i want to do like 4 graphs per row or 3 that screws it up. It is a bug?

Comment: try do like 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 graphs it wont work anymore. i dont know why

Comment: I don't no either, it's strange; But I don't know the `season` package and so the `plot.monthglm` function...

Comment: is there another way to approach this without the mfrow function?